# PyTorch: Row-wise Dot Product

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, dot-product

Suppose I have two tensors:

```
a = torch.randn(10, 1000, 1, 4)
b = torch.randn(10, 1000, 6, 4)
```

Where the third index is the index of a vector.

I want to take the dot product between each vector in `b` with respect to the vector in `a`.

To illustrate, this is what I mean:

```
dots = torch.Tensor(10, 1000, 6, 1)
for b in range(10):
     for c in range(1000):
           for v in range(6):
            dots[b,c,v] = torch.dot(b[b,c,v], a[b,c,0])
```

How would I achieve this using torch functions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
a = torch.randn(10, 1000, 1, 4)
b = torch.randn(10, 1000, 6, 4)

c = torch.sum(a * b, dim=-1)

print(c.shape)
```

torch.Size([10, 1000, 6])

```
c = c.unsqueeze(-1)
print(c.shape)
```

torch.Size([10, 1000, 6, 1])